# telerik MVC Grid Control - Looping through all the columns

Tags: telerik-mvc

How do I loop through all the columns in MVC Grid?
From what I have seems in all the samples it seems that the columns are static. In my case it is dynamic and I want set the property at run time.

Is it possible to set some property say encode for all the columns in a grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it was easy once I noted that for loop can be embedded in the columns section

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model.GetDataTable()).Name("MyTestGrid").Pageable().Sortable().Filterable().Groupable().Columns(
    columns=>
    {
        foreach (var column in Model.GetDataTable().Columns)
        {
            columns.Bound(column.ToString()).Encoded(false);
        }
    }
    ).Render();
```

Comment: Got the hint from [link](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/dynamic-column-titles-can-t-get-to-work.aspx)